# TextField.setConstraints null pointer exception

Tags: java-me, textfield, midp, lcdui

I have a TextField in a form:

```
private TextField cc1F = new TextField("", "", 250, TextField.ANY);
```

Once click button OK, then set cc1F field's Constraints to:

```
cc1F.setConstraints(TextField.UNEDITABLE);
```

then I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DefaultInputMethodHandler.setConstraints(+63)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField$InputMethodClientImpl.setConstraints(+20)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField.setConstraints(+37)
at com.zousys.j2me.zmail.gui.view.HeaderView.menuAction(+146)
```

.....................................

Anyone know this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in your device or emulator implementation of [TextField constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#TextField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int) "API javadocs") or [setConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#setConstraints(int)). Try testing with non-empty contents

Comment: thnks for the reply gnat....i solved it using StringItem and its working fine now.

Comment: that sounds like a good solution. As long as you don't intend to let user modify TextField contents, StringItem makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

The example of code was tested with simulator WTK 3.0 and device Samsung Chat 
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_ch@t_527-4096.php and the test passed. :)

I think that the problem is caused by device model or the object **cc1F** is null.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextBox;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;


public class TextFieldMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    private Form form;
    private Command cmdExit;
    private Command cmdSetConstraints;
    private Display display;
    private TextField textField;

    public TextFieldMIDlet() {
        form = new Form("Testing constraints");

        cmdExit = new Command("Exit",Command.EXIT, 1);
        cmdSetConstraints = new Command("Set Constraints",Command.ITEM, 1);
        textField = new TextField("", "", 250, TextField.ANY);

        form.addCommand(cmdExit);
        form.addCommand(cmdSetConstraints);
        form.append(textField);

        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        form.setCommandListener(this);
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {

        display.setCurrent(form);

    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {

        if (c == cmdExit) {

            this.notifyDestroyed();

        } else if (c == cmdSetConstraints) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Set...");

                if (textField.getConstraints() == TextField.UNEDITABLE) {
                    textField.setConstraints(TextField.ANY );
                } else {
                    textField.setConstraints(TextField.UNEDITABLE );
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```